# npm request conditional piping based on response

Tags: node.js, npm-request

I need to download a file by POSTing to a REST server.

I was first using `http` when it was `get`. But now i need to use POST, and node's http post is way too complicated, I dont want to build a low level request, so I dont want to use it.

I am now using `request`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Now, my server either sends `{isUpdateAvailable:false}` or it sends a tar file.

So i need to save the file, or show 'Already up to date'. How do I pipe to a filestream by checking the response header?

I need to set the pipe along with the request code, so I'm not able to separate the code properly. I need to `fs.createWriteStream` only if its necessary. Will it be possible?

So, how do i do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407928/pipe-after-successful-condition-node-js/51408453#51408453