# Pipe after successful condition Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-statements

```
request.get(fileLink)
    .on('response', function(response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.headers['content-type'] == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
           return true;
        } else {
         return false;
        }
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.xls'));
```

I need to save file if response code is 200 and content-type is application/vnd.ms-excel. How to organize code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it, is to pipe `response` if the condition is met, and destroy the `response` stream otherwise.

```
request.get(fileLink)
    .on('response', function(response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.headers['content-type'] == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
            return response
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data.xls'))
                .on('error', console.error)
        }

        response.destroy();
    });
```

Comment: response.destroy() is used to avoid memory leak?

Comment: Try it without `destroy`, the request won't end until the whole data is emitted. This way you close the stream, disregarding any data, since you don't care about it.

Comment: console.error or console.error()?

Comment: `console.error` since `on('error'` takes a function. In case of error, it will call `console.error()`. it's equivalent to: `on('error', err => console.error(err))`

Comment: oh, yeah, it's call back